# Is there a way to run the supplied prisma query as a raw sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

I have been stuck with this and similar dilemmas for a while now and can't seem to find an acceptable solution. Prisma currently doesn't allow for upsertMany in it's queries, or in my case a nested upsertMany. I have found some accepted solutions and the most popular one is using $transaction from prisma to write a loop of upserts which doesn't work for me as each query contains up to 200 items to upsert (currently testing 100 items takes roughly 10sec to run so it really isn't an acceptable solution). Prisma offers the ability to use $queryRaw to use a raw SQL query which may offer a more acceptable solution. I've supplied the code to their currently accepted solution as well as the query (that isn't currently possible) that I'm hoping someone could help me turn into a raw sql query or a better solution.

Their accepted solution:

```
prisma.$transaction(data.map((d) => 
 prisma.MODEL.upsert({
  where:{
   id: d.id
  },
  update:{
   foo:d.foo,
  },
  create:{
   foo: d.foo,
   bar: d.bar
  },
 }),
 ),
);
```

How I would need to implement it as I would like to create one MODEL with a related array of MODELS and another array of related MODELS:

```
let transactionOne = prisma.$transaction(
 arrayOne.map((d)=>
  prisma.MODEL.upsert({
   where:{
    id: d.id,
   },
   update:{
    foo: d.foo,
   },
   create:{
    foo: d.foo,
    bar: d.bar,
   },
  }),
 )
);

let transactionTwo = prisma.$transaction(
 arrayTwo.map((d)=>
  prisma.MODEL.upsert({
   where:{
    id: d.id,
   },
   update:{
    foo: d.foo,
   },
   create:{
    foo: d.foo,
    bar: d.bar,
   },
  }),
 )
);

let data = await prisma.MODEL.create({
 data:{
  foo: foo, 
  bar: bar,
  example:{
   connect: transactionOne.map((a)=>({id: a.id})),
  },
  exampleTwo:{
   connect: transactionTwo.map((b)=>({id: b.id})),
  },
},
});
```

My example above like mentioned before takes just over 10 seconds with 100 items and may possibly require 200 items so 20 seconds per call. Is there an easier way to make this faster or like I said a way to create a raw SQL query with the same results?

Thanks for any help!